# Program is starved (no output) after adding usleep() in the threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

So I'm simulation a car intersection with four queues (for each direction) and a global intersection Q. The program runs fine without the usleep (which is commented out). But when I use usleep, nothing happens.

I'm sure its because the localID that gets pushed into the globalQ is different than the one that gets pushed in the local (directional) queue.
So this line "if ((localID == northQ.front()) && (localID == globalQ.front()))"
is never satisfied.

Reason I am introducing "usleep(getrand(100000, 3000000));" is because I want to add some randomness to the cars' speeds. I know it might be a bit confusing. But the major point is the program runs without the sleep command. But when I introduce it, nothing happens... Some starvation I guess.

EDIT: The main 4 functions are the same thing. Just different queue names.

EDIT2: The program works if I sleep for a certain amount of time. It doesn't work when that time is a random number in some interval that I specify.

The code:

```
// Instructions
// Change the CARS and RUN_TIME variable to the desired values.
// Compile in command line using: g++ -pthread Intelligent_Traffic_Light_System.cpp -o run.exe
// Run in command line by using: ./run.exe

#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdlib> //for rand()
#include <unistd.h> // for usleep()
#include <ctime> //for clock(), clock_t, CLOCKS_PER_SEC

#define CARS 10 // # cars coming from each direction. 40 cars total
#define RUN_TIME 125 // 125 seconds (5 seconds longer than it should take to run)

using namespace std;

int globalID; // global ID for each car arriving at the intersection

// a queue for each direction.
queue<int> northQ;
queue<int> eastQ;
queue<int> southQ;
queue<int> westQ;
queue<int> globalQ;

pthread_t threadID;

// a lock for each queue/direction.
pthread_mutex_t northLock;
pthread_mutex_t eastLock;
pthread_mutex_t southLock;
pthread_mutex_t westLock;
pthread_mutex_t globalQlock;

pthread_mutex_t globalIDLock; // lock for changing the globalid (i.e. car id)
pthread_mutex_t intersectionLock; // lock for one car passing through the intersection


int getrand(int min,int max) //random number generator between min and max
{
         return(rand()%(max-min)+min);
}


void init()
{
    globalID = 1; //first car will have ID = 1
    pthread_mutex_init(&northLock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&eastLock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&southLock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&westLock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&globalIDLock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&intersectionLock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&globalQlock, NULL);
}

// Now will test to create an intersection with only 1 direction. North
void *north(void *null)
{

    int localID;
    double duration; //for checking how long a car will be waiting at the front of its lane
    clock_t start; //variable will be used to calculate wait time

    pthread_mutex_lock(&northLock); // locking the queue
    pthread_mutex_lock(&globalIDLock); // locking globalIDLock mutex in order to update globalID
    localID = globalID++; // update globalID after reserving that ID for a car in north lane
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalIDLock);
    northQ.push(localID); // pushing the local car into northQ.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&northLock);

    //usleep(getrand(100000, 3000000)); //lets say it takes somewhere between 1/10th of a second and 3 seconds to get to the intersection.
    start = clock(); // Now the car has arrived at intersection. Let's start the timer.

    pthread_mutex_lock(&globalQlock);
    globalQ.push(localID);//pushing car into global (intersection Q)
    //cout << localID <<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalQlock);

    while(1) //Checking cars properties here
    {
        if ((localID == northQ.front()) && (localID == globalQ.front())) // Current Car is in the front of the lane... Lets Proceed
        {
            break;
        }
        else //Current car is not in front on its lane. Lets wait
        {
            usleep(10); // sleep for 10 microsecond to allow for other cars to proceed if they must
            continue;
        }
    }

    // Car is in the front so let's proceed to allow it to pass through intersection.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&intersectionLock); // need to lock the intersection. Function call will block until mutex is available
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    northQ.pop();
    globalQ.pop();
    cout << "Car from NORTH lane with ID: " << localID << " ENTERING the intersection." << endl;
    cout << "It has been waiting at the light for: "<< duration<<" seconds."<<endl;
    sleep(3);
    cout << "Car from NORTH lane with ID: " << localID << " LEAVING the intersection." << endl<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&intersectionLock); // give other cars a chance to pass
}


void *east(void *null)
{

    int localID;
    double duration;
    clock_t start;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&eastLock); // locking the queue
    pthread_mutex_lock(&globalIDLock); // locking globalIDLock mutex in order to update globalID
    localID = globalID++; // update globalID after reserving that ID for a car in north lane
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalIDLock);
    eastQ.push(localID); // pushing the local car into northQ.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&eastLock);

    //usleep(getrand(100000, 3000000)); //lets say it take 1/10th of a second to get to the intersection.
    start = clock();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&globalQlock);
    globalQ.push(localID);//pushing car into global queue (i.e. intersection queue)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalQlock);


    while(1) //Checking cars properties here
    {
        if ((localID == eastQ.front()) && (localID == globalQ.front())) // Current Car is in the front of the lane... Lets Proceed
        {
            break;
        }
        else //Current car is not in front on its lane. Lets wait
        {
            usleep(10); // sleep for 10 microsecond to allow for other cars to proceed if they must
            continue;
        }
    }

    // Car is in the front so let's proceed to allow it to pass through intersection.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&intersectionLock); // need to lock the intersection. Function call will block until mutex is available
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    eastQ.pop();
    globalQ.pop();

    cout << "Car from EAST lane with ID:  " << localID << " ENTERING the intersection." << endl;
    cout << "It has been waiting at the light for: "<<duration<<" seconds."<<endl;
    sleep(3);
    cout << "Car from EAST lane with ID:  " << localID << " LEAVING the intersection." << endl <<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&intersectionLock); // give other cars a chance to pass
}


void *south(void *null)
{

    int localID;
    double duration;
    clock_t start;

    pthread_mutex_lock (&southLock); // locking the queue
    pthread_mutex_lock (&globalIDLock); // locking globalIDLock mutex in order to update globalID
    localID = globalID++; // update globalID after reserving that ID for a car in north lane
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&globalIDLock);
    southQ.push(localID); // pushing the local car into northQ.
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&southLock);

    //usleep(getrand(100000, 3000000)); //lets say it take 1/10th of a second to get to the intersection.
    start = clock();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&globalQlock);
    globalQ.push(localID);//pushing car into global (intersection Q)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalQlock);


    while(1) //Checking cars properties here
    {
        if ((localID == southQ.front()) && (localID == globalQ.front())) // Current Car is in the front of the lane... Lets Proceed
        {
            break;
        }
        else //Current car is not in front on its lane. Lets wait
        {
            usleep(10); // sleep for 10 microsecond to allow for other cars to proceed if they must
            continue;
        }

    }

    // Car is in the front so let's proceed to allow it to pass through intersection.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&intersectionLock); // need to lock the intersection. Function call will block until mutex is available
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    southQ.pop();
    globalQ.pop();

    cout << "Car from SOUTH lane with ID: " << localID << " ENTERING the intersection." << endl;
    cout << "It has been waiting at the light for: "<<duration<< " seconds."<<endl;
    sleep(3);
    cout << "Car from SOUTH lane with ID: " << localID << " LEAVING the intersection." << endl<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&intersectionLock); // give other cars a chance to pass
}


void *west(void *null)
{

    int localID;
    double duration;
    clock_t start;

    pthread_mutex_lock (&westLock); // locking the queue
    pthread_mutex_lock (&globalIDLock); // locking globalIDLock mutex in order to update globalID
    localID = globalID++; // update globalID after reserving that ID for a car in north lane
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&globalIDLock);
    westQ.push(localID); // pushing the local car into northQ.
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&westLock);

    //usleep(getrand(100000, 3000000));
    start = clock();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&globalQlock);
    globalQ.push(localID);//pushing car into global (intersection Q)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalQlock);



    while(1) //Checking cars properties here
    {
        if ((localID == westQ.front()) && (localID == globalQ.front())) // Current Car is in the front of the lane... Lets Proceed
        {
            break;
        }
        else //Current car is not in front on its lane. Lets wait
        {
            usleep(10); // sleep for 10 microsecond to allow for other cars to proceed if they must
            continue;
        }

    }

    // Car is in the front so let's proceed to allow it to pass through intersection.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&intersectionLock); // need to lock the intersection. Function call will block until mutex is available
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    westQ.pop();
    globalQ.pop();
    cout << "Car from WEST lane with ID:  " << localID << " ENTERING the intersection." << endl;
    cout << "It has been waiting for: "<< duration <<" seconds."<< endl;
    sleep(3);
    cout << "Car from WEST lane with ID:  " << localID << " LEAVING the intersection." << endl<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&intersectionLock); // give other cars a chance to pass
}


int main()
{
    init();

    for(int i = 0; i < CARS; i++) //first car will be car with ID 1; Last ID is 40
    {
        pthread_create (&threadID, NULL, north, NULL);
        pthread_create (&threadID, NULL, east, NULL);
        pthread_create (&threadID, NULL, south, NULL);
        pthread_create (&threadID, NULL, west, NULL);
    }
    sleep(RUN_TIME); //sleep for sufficient times to allow for all threads to finish running.

    cout << "Finished." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this really the **[minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**?

Comment: [The useconds argument shall be less than one million. If the value of useconds is 0, then the call has no effect.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the main thread exits before the "north"-"east" etc threads terminate:

1. When I put the `sleep(RUN_TIME)` inside the main loop, the program starts working.
2. The reason of the early termination is the `(localID == globalQ.front())` not synchronized code located inside each "north"-"east" function. This code, as you have correctly mentioned, is never (almost) satisfied and causes to busy wait inside the `while(1)` loop.